# Angular enviando dados com token

Tags: angularjs, .net, token

Pessoal uma duvida que para muitos e bem basica, mas nao entendi ainda, eu tenho uma aplicacao em .net e uma outra em angular recebendo o token, as duas estao OK com a autenticacao e o armazenamento do Token, minha duvida e se quando eu precisar enviar os dados de um formulario eu devo enviar eles no corpo do arquivo como um post normal? Ou teria uma outra boa pratica para esse envio?